# 449 status code for the background images included in css

Tags: css, hosting

I have the following snippet in css:

```
.doubleline {
    background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/double.gif) repeat-x 100% 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And the problem is that this image is not always displayed on the html-page. 
Fiddler shows 449 status for http://.../wp-content/uploads/2018/double.gif

Initially, this file was in http://.../wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/img/ folder as it's the theme file but the result was the same.

Several times this file was displayed on the page, then disappeared, displayed again, disappeared and the pattern is unclear.
The problem is not in the browser cache, it's clear.

What means 449 and what can cause this problem?

Comment: Error code 449 itself isn't difficult to find. The [official Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd891478.aspx) about the error says "The 449 Retry With status code indicates that the request cannot be satisfied because insufficient information was provided by the client.". However, it doesn't mention what information it needs exactly.

Comment: yes. As I understand,  insufficient information in my case is when style.css requests the image.

Comment: ... Which would be a bit silly, because then this CSS wouldn't work anywhere, ever. But it does. So maybe is wrong with the setup on your server. I'm afraid I couldn't tell you what to look for though. Maybe someone else can come along.